# Why is max([1.0,1]) 1.0 and max([1,1.0]) 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> max([1.0,1])
1.0
>>> max([1,1.0])
1
>>> 1==1.0
True
```

Why is `max()` returning the first value that the list has?

Comment: What would you expect it to return?

Comment: It does return the element at the first index if it is the maximum element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Python's official documentation of the max() function:

`If multiple items are maximal, the function returns the first one encountered.`

Since 1.0 == 1, whichever comes first between 1.0 and 1 is returned by the function.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is [how the function is specified to work](http://web.archive.org/web/20190729032036/https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

> If multiple items are maximal, the function returns the first one encountered. This is consistent with other sort-stability preserving tools such as `sorted(iterable, key=keyfunc, reverse=True)[0]` and `heapq.nlargest(1, iterable, key=keyfunc)`.